# Bootstrap dropdown menu closes its container menu when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a Bootstrap dropdown menu on my website, it works fine on desktops and screens larger than 737px, but when it's less than that, the dropdown menu just closes the hamburger menu containing it.

[image: Image of the menu here]

I am using the latest Bootstrap through their CDN and I have checked through this website for answers and also checked their JavaScript to see if there was a problem, but I found nothing, I have also tried `stopPropagation`, but that didn't help neither.

What am I missing?

Comment: Share code bud?

Comment: share code of what you have done so far